# non blocking frameset (async)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous

I'm not here to argue about the fact that we still use frameset for a part of our application this will get replaced eventually (famous last words) but for the time being I want to increase the performance.

If I take a simple example of what I have:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
 <frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

The point is that frame_b gets loaded after frame_a is actually ready. Even tho the 'network' tab in every browser will prove different, the frames load one by one. If I load frame_a it will take 0.5 seconds, if I load frame_b it will take 0.7 seconds.
Yet if I load both as above example, frame_a will still take 0.5 seconds, while frame_b suddenly takes 1.2 seconds (0.5+0.7) to load. Hence I assume the browser just 'blocks' the request until frame_a is ready.

Now I have tried multiple things. I tried some onload stuff with JS/Jquery yet no matter what I try I always end up with the same result.

Is there any way to actually load this "async"? And with this I do not mean to load the 'main' page first (that includes the frameset) but that the frames (a and b) gets loaded async so my total execution time gets halved?

I simply cannot change a lot of the code, but if someone can figure out a way to 'easy' replace these frames while keeping the exact functionality, ill be happy too :)

Comment: This SO post claims that frames load async: [How is a frameset loaded in a browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912091/how-is-a-frameset-loaded-in-a-browser).  So might the delay be on the server rather than client side? Just a thought.

Comment: Well good thinking. I tested this on a local server (IIS btw) with nobody else on it. I really would not know where to look for (server side). There is, as far as I know not a limit on the amount of connections one person can make. Only a total limit. Even so the SO post looks decent, I do not really see 'proof', while I had my own example stating the obvious. I might try to craft some test cases on different systems.